# JS - need to use wildcard

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, wildcard

in relation to the woocommerce product add-on (inadequate) I've set up a datepicker function, but for the respective product items to utilize this - I need to add the following script to the javascript provision in the theme:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $("input[name='addon-2778-delivery-date[delivery-date]'" ).datepicker({
            dateFormat : 'dd-mm-yy'
        });
    });
</script>
```

2778 is the product ID generated by Wordpress or woocommerce. So I need to replace this script with one that uses a wildcard instead of the literal number. The rest on the 'name' is the same for all.

Any help appreciated. Cheers, Peter

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

```
$("input[name*='-delivery-date[delivery-date]'" )
```

Comment: What a legend !! It appears to be working correctly. Well done. Thanks, Peter.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is probably the [jQuery attribute ends with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector)

E.g.
`$("input[name$='-delivery-date[delivery-date]'")`

This will have more accuracy in your case than the contains selector.

Comment: Thanks Dave. Appreciated.